# Angular module lazy loading, router children not displaying component

Tags: angular

**app.component.html**

```
<a routerLink="./">Main Home</a> &nbsp;| &nbsp;
<a routerLink="./contactus">ContactUs</a> &nbsp;| &nbsp;
<a routerLink="./productmodule">Product Manager</a> &nbsp;| &nbsp;
<a routerLink="./customermodule">Customer Manager</a> &nbsp;| &nbsp;
<a routerLink="./ordermodule">Order Manager</a> &nbsp;| &nbsp;
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

**app.main.router**

```
import { Routes, RouterModule } from "@angular/router";
import { AppComponents } from "../Resource/app.Resource";
// import { ContactUsComponent } from "../Components/app.contactus.component";
 import { LandingComponent } from "../Components/LandingComponent";
 import { ContactUsComponent } from "../Components/app.contactus.component";

export const appRouters:Routes= [
    {path:'', component : LandingComponent},
    {path: "contactus",component :  ContactUsComponent },
    { path: "productmodule", loadChildren: "./Product.Module#ProductModule" },
]

export const appRouting = RouterModule.forRoot(appRouters);
```

**Main Module**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { AppRoutingModule } from "./app.routing.module";
import { AppComponents, AppBootComponent, AppServices } from './ngObjects/Resource/app.Resource';
import {ProductComponents  } from "./SubModules/LazyModules/ProductManager/ngObjects/Resources/Product.Resources";

//import { appRouting } from "./ngObjects/Router/AppRouter";
//import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ...AppComponents,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    CommonModule,
    AppRoutingModule,

  ],
  providers: [...AppServices],
  bootstrap: [...AppBootComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }


import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { appRouting } from "./ngObjects/Router/AppRouter";

@NgModule({
    imports: [appRouting],
    exports: [RouterModule],
    providers: []
  })
  export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

**lazy module script** 
*child html*

```
<h1>Product Manager</h1>
<a routerLink="">Back</a> &nbsp;| &nbsp;
<a routerLink="home">Product Home</a> &nbsp;| &nbsp;
<a routerLink="new">New Product</a> &nbsp;| &nbsp;
<a routerLink="list">List Product</a> &nbsp;| &nbsp;
```

**child router**

```
import { Routes, RouterModule } from "@angular/router";
import { NewProductComponent} from "../Components/product.newitem.component";
import { ProductManagerComponent } from "../Components/Product.Manager.Component";
import { ProductHomeComponent } from "../Components/Product.Home.Component";
import { ModuleWithProviders } from "@angular/core";

export const productRouters: Routes= [

    {path:'',  component: ProductManagerComponent,

    children: [
            { path: '', redirectTo:"home" }, 
            { path: 'home', component: ProductHomeComponent  },        
            { 
                path:'new',  
                component: NewProductComponent,
            },
      ]
    },
    // { path: '', redirectTo:"home" }, 
    // { path: "home", component: ProductHomeComponent  },        
    // { 
    //     path:'new',  
    //     component: NewProductComponent,
    // },
];

export const productRouting = RouterModule.forChild(productRouters);
```

**lazy module**

```
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";

import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { productRouting} from "./SubModules/LazyModules/ProductManager/ngObjects/Router/product.router";
import {ProductComponents, ProductServices } from "./SubModules/LazyModules/ProductManager/ngObjects/Resources/Product.Resources";
//import {ProductManagerComponent} from "./SubModules/LazyModules/ProductManager/ngObjects/Components/Product.Manager.Component"
//import {NewProductComponent } from "./SubModules/LazyModules/ProductManager/ngObjects/Components/product.newitem.component";

@NgModule(
{
    imports:[
        CommonModule,
        FormsModule,
        productRouting,
    ],
    declarations:[
        ...ProductComponents,
 //           NewProductComponent,
 //           ProductManagerComponent,
    ],
    exports:[
       // ...Produ

ctComponents,            
        ],
        providers:[
            ...ProductServices,
        ],
        entryComponents:[
            //...ProductComponents,
        ]
    }
)
export class ProductModule
{

}
```

When I click at child/lazy module routerLink browser's link updated properly but component not showing in the outlet area,

When I add router-outlet in both main and child router html, an exception raised.

```
ProductManagerComponent.html:6 ERROR Error: No component factory found for ProductHomeComponent. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?
```

If I removed `< router-outlet > < / router-outlet` > from child router html,
error removed but components not shows if I move path from children routerlinks to parent node in lazy module, the components of lazy module are appeared but links are removed.

Can some let me what is the mistake in the code ?

Comment: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/fork/angular) MVCE please?

Have you tried adding that component to your `entryComponents` array in your `@NgModule` decorator?

Try following the [lazy loading tutorial's](https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules) every step

Comment: Can you show the code of the ProductHomeComponent?